# What internal dictionary does FxCop use?

Tags: dictionary, fxcop

FxCop must base itself on some internal dictionary.

Does it use Word dictionaries if they are installed?

When running FxCop on my build server it doesn't find any spelling errors, but on my developer machine it does.

I am aware of the custom dictionary, but it is not the issue in this case. On the build server it accepts any word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the version. FxCop 1.35 uses Microsoft Office's spell checking, but FxCop 1.36 [ships with the spell checker libraries](http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/06/08/fxcop-now-ships-with-the-spell-checker-libraries.aspx).

If you're using 1.35, I guess Word is installed on your dev box, but not on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Word 2007 + proofing tools are installed on both boxes. But I will accept and move towards upgrading from 1.35 -> 1.36.

Only difference I can find is that Word 2003 + proofing tools -have been- installed on the developer machine and not on the build server.

Comment: It might very well be the case that FxCop 1.35 needs Word 2003. Don't know for sure, since I switched to 1.36 before moving to Office 2007...